# How to create a loop to feed back the result as new param of the function? (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

My current script is:

```
function F
{
     param ([int]$OF)
     $OF / 2
}

$OF = 100

if ((F $OF) -ge 2)
{
     F (F $OF)
}
```

The result is 25 now. But what I want to do is to add a loop to this script. Within the loop, the result `F (F $OF)` will be fed back as the new `$OF` of the function. Then the function runs again. It will not stop feeding back the result until the result is `-lt 2`. The whole process is more like the optimization: keep reducing the value until it meets the objective. However, I am not sure how to create such a loop. Use FOR LOOP? Or DO UNTIL LOOP?

Comment: The functionality you are referring to is called ***recursion***. The question is do you want a *recursive* function (one that calls itself), to just loop the function until it is -le 2, or to loop until it is -le 2 and the last time to (a *while* loop or *do-while* loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original description in your question seems to point to a [recursive method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) as a *recursive function* can run until a *condition* is met (in the same manner as a loop). In this case a simple [while loop](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/12/12/understanding-the-powershell-while-statement.aspx) or [do/while](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/05/05/powershell-looping-understanding-and-using-do-while.aspx) loop would probably work but this also provides an excellent opportunity to learn about recursion for later problems or assignments (such as flattening arrays or sorting/searching problems).

### Simple Recursive Method

A note on the code: it is good coding practice to start learning naming standards. In this case, variables created within functions shouldn't have the same name as other functions (unless a [$global](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849(v=wps.630).aspx) is needed) and one letter functions are rarely a good idea - both of these can cause confusion and make code hard to parse later.

```powershell
function CalculateF #changed from F
{
     param ([int] $cur_of) #changed from $OF so no confusion with calling variable

     $cur_of

     if ($cur_of -gt 2)
     {
        CalculateF -cur_of ($cur_of/2) # calls itself with halved value
     }
}

$OF = 100

if (CalculateF -cur_of $OF -ge 2) #changed these function calls to call the parameter directly
{
     CalculateF -cur_of $OF
}
```

This function runs, prints the value of the *current OF* (`cur_of`), checks to see if the value of `cur_of` is *greater than* 2. Than `CalculateF` calls itself (that is simple *recursion*) with `cur_of/2`. Or if it is not it completes the function.

### For Loop Version

As @Kiran already put a version with a do/while loop and function - I'll put the [for loop](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4542.powershell-loops.aspx#For) version which does not require or make sense with a function at all. As a for loop can perform simple mathematical calculations on the iterator not just +/- 1, as such:

```
$val = 100

for ($i=$val; $i -ge 2; $i /= 2)
{
  # Sets iterator to value and loops through (dividing by 2 each time)
  [int] $i
}
```

***Note***: Tested above with `powershell -version 2 ./scriptname.ps1` to ensure no versioning issues

Comment: Absolutely helpful! I was trying to use Recursive Method last night, but I may make some stupid mistakes. :-(   I will check my script later.

Answer (score 2):

couple of ways to do this:

```
function F
{
 param ([int]$OF)
 do 
 {
    $result = $of / 2
    $of = $result
    $result
 }
 while( $result -gt 2)

}



f -OF 200
```

-OR

```
function F2
{
   param ([int]$OF)

   $of / 2
}

#Declare the parameter value
$val = 100


do
{
  $result = F2 -OF $val
  $val = $result
  $result
}
while($result -gt 2)
```

Comment: Two notes: Your functions will display floats (.5 results) which is not an error but something to be aware of (the *int* cast points to a possible rounding need). Also you do not need all those assignments. For example, the second one could just be `$val = F2 -OF $val` and then `$val`

Comment: Well, I do not quite understand the meaning of `$val = F2 -OF $val`. What is the `-OF`?

Comment: `OF`  is the parameter from your function f :). i just reused it. Powershell functions are called like so:  `Function -ParameterName ParameterValue`. This is to avoid assignment issues between named and positional parameters. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj554301.aspx